# Setting folder permissions across domain

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, cross-domain

I have an application that is used to perform a number of operations for segregating users on a domain such as creating Active Directory sturctures, users and groups as well as assigning users to different groups.

Once everything is created in AD I want to assign access to a newly created folder for one of my newly created AD groups.

I want to run the application from a local machine on a different domain, rather than having to log onto a machine in the domain and then run the application from there.

Everything in my application seems to work fine from local machine apart from setting the access rule; which fails with:

"Some or all identity references could not be translated".

The code works fine when running from within the domain.  I have also tried using impersonation but this makes no difference

```
if (Directory.Exists(sDirectory))
    {
      using (Impersonation impUser = new Impersonation(sAdminUserName, _sDomain, sAdminPassword))
      {
        DirectoryInfo diClientDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(sDirectory);
        DirectorySecurity dsClientDirectory = diClientDirectory.GetAccessControl();
        FileSystemAccessRule fsAccessRules = new FileSystemAccessRule(sSecurityGroup, FileSystemRights.FullControl, (InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit), PropagationFlags.InheritOnly, AccessControlType.Allow);

        **dsClientDirectory.AddAccessRule(fsAccessRules);  //THIS LINE THROWS THE EXCEPTION**
        diClientDirectory.SetAccessControl(dsClientDirectory);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually means the group granted permissions does not exist or could not be resolved on the target machine. Check whether a group exists in the target domain with that name or a suitable trust relationship exists between the domains.

Comment: Thanks, however, as mentioned, the code runs successfully when running on the machine within the domain so i would have thought it unlikely to be your first suggestion of the group not existing, otherwise that should fail too? The group definitely exists as it is created earlier in the code, or even earlier in the week during testing! It could be a resolution issue though...  All other operatins work such as creating the AD objects and the directory itself so i would have thought the trust is fine.  It is only permissions that fails

Answer (score 0):

Like akton said, check the trust relationship between your ADs.

Moreover, check your running environment. I had this kind of issues when I had to touch at AD through C#: if the user doesn't have permissions to do this kind of modifications on the other AD, it will fail.

And last point, the group name and path. Does your group name contains the domain name (sSecurityGroup) ? Maybe your directory path has a path issue (sDirectory) ?

Comment: As i am trying using impersonation then i would have thought the user definitely has the permissions as i am impersonating the user i use to RDP into a machine in domain B and run the app from there - which works without error.  I haven't put the domain name in the group name so will try that.  the Directory path appears to be OK when i step through the code but i will try with a fully qualified directory path. Thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck with this approach? I am having the same issue here and can't create folders in a foreign domain with c# (despite impersonation)